# Securing fetched data with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, security

So this week I'm going to secure my PHP application as much as possible. I retrieve data from the database a lot, so I need some basic tips that would help me secure the below code.

Thanks, im just a newbie.

```
<?php

mysqli_select_db($connect,"users");
$select="select * from members";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$select);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);


//this is what i want to secure -- down

$a = $row['name'];
$b = $row['add'];
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you suppose is insecure about that?  You are storing data in PHP variables on the server.  Nothing has even been sent to the browser yet.

Comment: In what manner do you want to secure it?  As far as I can see, there isn't any vulnerability there at all.  Now, there may be in the greater code, but you need to specify what you're talking about

Answer (score 1):

Encode **everything** from user input / database you want to display in the browser with `htmlspecialchars()` to avoid [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: Do not use `htmlentities`.  Use the proper function which in this case would be [`htmlspecialchars`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), and you **need** to set the proper characterset.  `htmlentities` is completely unrelated to security from any standpoint other than the fact it's a superset of htmlspecialchars functionality.

Comment: UPS! You are absolutely right, thanks! I've changed my answer from htmlentities to htmlspecialchars.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to secure BEFORE sending data to the DB (against SQL injection), and BEFORE outputting to html (against XSS). Those things are important, while inside your script almost everything is pretty much harmless (and can lead to errors on subsequent codes, btw).

Answer (score 0):

At first hand, do you have any security when inputing data in your database ?
You code may be vurnalable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) if you do not sanitize your data when inserting into the database. For that - check this function http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Another thing is that, html and javascript can be inserted in your database, and if you do not escape it and use print that data to HTML, you are vurnalable to [Cross-Site-Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) . You should escape your data using http://bg.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php. or http://bg.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Security is a big topic, but this can be a start for you - escape your input first, then take care of the output.